# Espresso - typeText not working

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm trying to type some text inside an EditText:

```
    public void testSearch() {
          onView(withId(R.id.titleInput)).perform(typeText("Engineer"));
          onView(withId(R.id.titleInput)).check(matches(withText("Engineer")));
    }
```

I see the EditText is getting focus, but nothing happens. No text is typed.

I tried this on a phone and an emulator - same result.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks like I figured out the issue. It had to do with hardware vs software keyboard.

**For Emulators:**

Go to Settings -> Language & Input -> switch the Default Input to Sample Soft Keyboard.

**For Phones:**

Install a software keyboard from the Play store and switch to it. It appears that the native keyboards of some phones do not work.

It works now.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Finally, after an hour trying to figure out what could be wrong with my espresso tests :)  Just had to change the keyboard.

Answer (score 19):

Had the same issue using Espresso 2. As a workaround I'm using replaceText instead of typeText.

```
public void testSearch() {
      onView(withId(R.id.titleInput)).perform(click(), replaceText("Engineer"));
      onView(withId(R.id.titleInput)).check(matches(withText("Engineer")));
}
```

Comment: Using `replaceText` worked for me. There is definitely some bug in `typeText`

Answer (score 16):

If the EditText does not has the focus yet, you should click on it first. If this solves your problem, then there is no bug.

```
onView(withId(R.id.titleInput)).perform(click()).perform(typeText("Engineer"));
```

Comment: Nope. It was the first thing I tried. Same issue even if you click on it first.

Comment: Thanks, it solved my issue because I listen to focus changes.

Comment: Not sure how Espresso was working in 2013, when you answered, but now the click/focus is taken care of by `ViewActions.typeText()`

Answer (score 11):

You can bypass the problem by calling setText on the EditText.

```
   final EditText titleInput = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.titleInput);
   getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            titleInput.setText("Engineer");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. This definitely unblocks me, so I'll award you the bounty. However, I still would like to know why typeText is not working in this case.

Comment: The solution might work fine but I think ethically this is not the right way. When Espresso has revealed an API that lets you do this, then I think we should concentrate on the bug. Why not open a bug on their site or discuss on google groups.

Comment: hi Eduard, I agree with Khushboo , you should file a bug on Espresso site. Perhaps, another widget in the screen has gained the focus.

Comment: I had a test case where I have to include multiple spaces after the username and using Espresso's typeText was including a dot (default if you tap double spaces) so this solved my issue. Thanks @skyleecm

Answer (score 5):

You can include it with in the code like this,

```
onView(withId(R.id.titleInput))
     .perform(click(), replaceText("Engineer"), closeSoftKeyboard());
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't need to add `click()` & `closeSoftKeyboard()` though

Answer (score 5):

Same issue resolved with the following:

```
editText.perform(scrollTo(), click(), clearText(), typeText(myInput), closeSoftKeyboard())
```

Interestingly, I only ever had a problem when my machine was working hard.

Comment: Thank you Mike, this work for me: myField.perform(scrollTo(), click(), clearText(), typeText(textToBeSet), closeSoftKeyboard())

Comment: Perfect answer, only one that reliably worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by setting `layout_height="wrap_content"` on the View I wanted to `click()`. Maybe it can help someone here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Genymotion, you may need to switch the default keyboard in Genymotion Configuration (it's an app on the emulator).

1. Go to Apps -> Genymotion Configuration -> Keyboard -> Virtual keyboard (click "Yes" when you're prompted to reboot)

NOTE: These changes do not persist after you close the emulator. You will need to set this every time you start the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

for me I was annotated my test method with `@UiThreadTest`. I removed that and it solved.

Comment: it doesn't help in this case
you should receive another error if the issue was in threading

Answer (score 0):

Adding `closeSoftKeyboard()` after `typeText()` worked for me.

**CODE:**

```
onView(withId(R.id.editTextUserInput))
            .perform(typeText(STRING_TO_BE_TYPED), closeSoftKeyboard());
```

This is how it is documented in the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing).