# Espresso - typeText() not working correclty, sometimes letters are missing

Tags: android, android-espresso

I start my login activity and I use in Espresso test:

```
onView(withId(R.id.username)).perform(typeText("USERNAME"));
```

I expect the text in the field to be "USERNAME", but sometimes I get "SERNAME", others "UERNAME".

Most of the times it works but sometimes it fails, specially after rebooting the phone.

Here is the sample code to reproduce the bug:
https://github.com/neoranga55/CleanGUITestArchitecture

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The test phone uses Swift keyboard with double language typing enabled. Apparently this causes the first appearance of the keyboard after phone boot to be slow but also auto-correct in a weird way the first letters of a word typed by Espresso.

Solution: always use **default system keyboard** on testing device/emulator and make sure a **software keyboard is enabled** to avoid [this other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436968/espresso-typetext-not-working).

Comment: Please see ejboy's answer, its a good workaround for this problem unless you are specifically testing keyboard input.

Answer (score 5):

You can also try `replaceText()`. It should not be affected by the slow IME:

`onView(withId(R.id.username)).perform(replaceText("USERNAME"));`

Comment: I tried to use it for SearchView but it is throwing exception as below
Error performing 'replace text()' on view 'with id: id/search'.

Comment: I upvoted it although this is a workaround, it is a good work around unless you are testing keyboard input there is no reason to not use replaceText, its faster and fixes the above problem. Good thinking.